# Knockout: implementing "focusing" on object from list

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In my root viewmodel I have observable array of `objects`.

I'd like to have drop-down list that allows user to select element of that list (lets call it `current`) and then be able to bind some `property` of selected object to some edit box.

So, to the user this should look like he\she can "focus" on some particular object (using combo-box) and then edit it's properties.

Right now in my html I have something like this:

```
<select data-bind="options: objects, optionsText: 'property', value: current, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

... for drop-down list, and:

```
<input data-bind="value: current.property"/>
```

... for property that should be edited.

Meanwhile, in js I do something like this:

```
function ObjectViewModel(p) {
  var self = this;
  self.property = ko.observable(p);
}

function AppViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.objects = ko.observableArray([
      new ObjectViewModel("id1"),
      new ObjectViewModel("id2")
  ]);
  self.current = ko.observable();
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

However, when I select value inside drop-down list nothing happens.

I suspect that I am not managing `current` property of `AppViewModel` correctly.

What is the correct way to implement this in knockout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had 2 problems with your code:

> 1. current is observable so to evaluate value you have to use "()".
> 2. "current().property" wont be accessible unless current is set. so to avoid failure put a check.
>      Hope this will help.

```js
function ObjectViewModel(p) {
  var self = this;
  self.property = ko.observable(p);
}

function AppViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.objects = ko.observableArray([
      new ObjectViewModel("id1"),
      new ObjectViewModel("id2")
  ]);
  self.current = ko.observable();
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: objects, optionsText: 'property', value: current, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>


<!-- ko if:current() -->
<h2 data-bind="text:current().property"></h2>
<input data-bind="value:current().property"/>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to make an improvement to Amit Bhoyar's answer (I think it's a thing of likes) I suggest you to use the **with** binding instead of **if** binding so you don't have to worry about call `current().property` to bind the value, **with** binding create the right context of current selected item and also ensure that the html block inside of it just get render with true-y values of **current** observable. I also changed the **value** binding to **textInput** binding to get a better application response to changes on the text input.

```js
function ObjectViewModel(p) {
  var self = this;
  self.property = ko.observable(p);
}

function AppViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.objects = ko.observableArray([
      new ObjectViewModel("id1"),
      new ObjectViewModel("id2")
  ]);
  self.current = ko.observable();
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: objects, optionsText: 'property', value: current, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>


<!-- ko with:current -->
<h2 data-bind="text: property"></h2>
<input data-bind="textInput: property"/>
<!-- /ko -->
```